# how to append an application to the raw IP and TCP layers

Tags: python, c, tcp

As you know, a packet can be described as this:

```
packet = ip_header + tcp_header + user_data
```

And we already know that the OSI layers go like this:

```
Physical layer
Data Link
Network (IP header)
Transport (TPC header)
Application
```

I already have the code for the IP headers and TCP headers.
I can create whatever code for an EMAIL application or an FTP application for example.
But the question is:
How can I interface the code of the application with the network Headers ?
so now suppose that "s" is a raw socket that I have already created.

Now I suppose I have to send it. In Python it would be like this:

```
s.sendto(packet, (dest_ip , 0 ))
```

and given that packet is:

```
packet = ip_header + tcp_header + user_data
```

User data (that is, the application) can be an FTP application, an email application, but that can get to be 5000 bytes long. How can I "send " that ? I just dont visualize it as part of a packet. Putting the whole FTP code between quotes? that sounds ridiculous. That is my missing link.

(Here is the question. How can I connect it to the raw headers I have created and have the whole stuff running? Yes, I want it to work on raw sockets

Thanks

Comment: What you show is not related in any way to FTP, but rather HTTP as it's a HTTP header. And yes, FTP (as well as HTTP and any other application-level protocol) is build upon TCP so it's all "user data".

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking about. You show a HTTP header, you talk about FTP and "Mailer" (do you mean SMTP or some Internet email program?). How is FTP and "Mailer" related to the HTTP header you show? Perhaps you need to learn more about [the OSI levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) and how they relate to TCP/IP?

Comment: And if you want to make an FTP program (server or client), why are you bothering with raw packets? That's really going to over-complicate your code, no matter application level protocol.

Comment: Maximum size of a packet depends on the lower-level layers. For example an [Ethernet frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame) can't be longer than about 1500 bytes. But then you have things like IP fragmentation that allows larger data to be split into multiple packets. And TCP which is a streaming protocol have no real limits at all as long as you split up the data in suitable chunks.

Comment: If you don't work on lower-levels with raw IP packets, there's really nothing you need to do. FTP can handle file-sizes in the multi-gigabyte range. How to split it, and at what limits, that should be part of the application layer protocol specification. Specifically for FTP it's all part of [RFC959](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc959).

Comment: NB TCP/IP doesn't have OSI layers. It has its own layers.

Answer (score 1):

> I can create whatever code for an EMAIL application or an FTP application for example. But the question is: How can I interface the code of the application with the network Headers ? so now suppose that "s" is a raw socket that I have already created.

By not using raw sockets.

Raw sockets are only useful if you're building a low-level network tool -- like `ping`, `mtr`, or `nmap` -- which specifically needs to interact with lower layers of the network stack. Most typical network applications, like an email client or an FTP application, have no need to do this, so they will use TCP (stream) sockets.

If you insist on using raw sockets regardless, you've put yourself in the situation of having to reimplement IP and TCP within your application. Don't do this.